# Phonegap not showing up in Chrome remote debug

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome, debugging, phonegap

I'm trying to debug a Phonegapp app on my Android tablet running via the Phonegap developer app.

According to [this post](https://gonzalo123.com/2014/08/04/debugging-android-cordovaphonegap-apps-with-chrome/), and Google's own [remote debugging docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3), Phonegap should show up as a tab in DevTools > remote devices because Cordova is basically just a WebView (as I understand it.) The device is connected via USB and is successfully detected. Alas, this is all I see when my app is running on the device:

[image]

If I open Chrome on the tablet, and go to a page, it does show up, so it seems it's only the app it won't show. What am I doing wrong?

[Update:

I also found [this post](http://www.adamwadeharris.com/remote-debugging-in-phonegap-with-chrome-devtools/), which makes the process sound decidedly more complicated. However, it's 3 years old and talks about modifying a file (AndroidManifest.xml) that I don't have in my PG build, so I assume it's outdated.]